# How do I make an offline backup of a Snowflake database?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, database-backups

I have an application that used to run on Snowflake but was migrated to a SQL Managed Instance. i used SnowHub to export all the DDL and then zipped it up should I ever need to look up some source code for a deprecated report or other process.

But how do dump the entire database to a compressed file. You never know when an audit might come up and I might need to restore the data in the state it was a few months or years ago.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use UNLOADING to load data from your table to an internal/external stage in your preferred format.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-overview.html

Unfortunately, you cannot unload the whole database with one statement, but need to run one COPY INTO  per table. As an alternative you could write a procedure looping over your metadata about tables and run COPY INTO  per loop execution.